# Search CSV from subdirectory and add folder name as a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, glob

I want read csv's from different sub-directories in my working directory to create a combined csv file. The combined csv should have a column containing the sub-directory name from which that particular csv was read from.

This is what I tried.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*/*.csv'),recursive=True)]
list_subfolder = [f.name for f in os.scandir(ride_path) if f.is_dir()]

df_list = []

for i in range(len(all_filenames)):
    dir_name = list_subfolder[i]
    current_csv = all_filenames[i]
    data = pd.read_csv(current_csv)
    data["sub_folder"]= dir_name
    df_list.append(data)

combined_df = pd.concat(df_list)
combined_df.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False)
```

The problem is that, it adds sub-directories that does not have csvs' in them, which is wrong and problematic. What is the best way to this right.

Comment: I think you want `glob.glob('**/*.csv', recursive=True)`

Comment: That works, but the main problem is getting the folder names from which the csv's was read from as a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use us `os.path.split()`:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob("**/*.csv", recursive=True)]

df_list = []
for f in all_filenames:
    current_csv = f
    data = pd.read_csv(current_csv)
    data["sub_folder"] = os.path.split(f)[0]    # <-- [0] is directory [1] is filename
    df_list.append(data)

combined_df = pd.concat(df_list)
print(combined_df)
combined_df.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via `pathlib` module:

```
from pathlib import Path

inp_path =  Path('.') # specify the inp path. Here, ('.') means current working dir
df_list= []

for csv_file in inp_path.glob('**/*.csv'): # glob here will return generator obj which will yield csv file one by one
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    df['file_name'] = csv_file.parent # possible to get parent dir via pathlib
    df_list.append(df_list)


combined_df = pd.concat(df_list)
combined_df.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False)
```

**`Note`**.

1- use  `csv_file.parent.name` if you just need the name.

2- use  `csv_file.parent.absolute()` if you want the full path of parent dir.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `glob` and `os`:

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

df_list = []

for csv in glob.glob('**/*.csv', recursive=True):
    parent_folder = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(csv))[-1]
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    df['subfolder'] = parent_folder
    df_list.append(df)

combined_df = pd.concat(df_list)
combined_df.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

One-line method (adapted from the [@nk03](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15438033/nk03) answer).

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib as pth

pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csvfile).assign(file_name=csvfile.parent)
           for csvfile in pth.Path(".").glob("**/*.csv")]) \
  .to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False)
```